# How to calculate sum of repeating elements using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

========================================================================

```
**Input XML:** 
<Customers> 
<Customer>
    <Items> 
        <Item>
            <ItemId>5639</ItemId>
            <ProductName> Lawnmower </ProductName>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <USPrice>148.95</USPrice>
            <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemId>6000</ItemId>
            <ProductName>Baby Monitor</ProductName>
            <Quantity>2</Quantity>
            <USPrice>39.98</USPrice>
            <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Customer>
<Customer>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <ItemId>7000</ItemId>
            <ProductName> Cutter </ProductName>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            <USPrice>15.95</USPrice>
            <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <ItemId>9000</ItemId>
            <ProductName> Laptop </ProductName>
            <Quantity>5</Quantity>
            <USPrice>2048.95</USPrice>
            <Comment>Confirm this is electric</Comment>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Customer >
```

**Output XML:**

```
<Customers> 
    <Customer> 
        <TotalPurchase>sum(USPRice)</TotalPurchase> 
    </Customer> 
    <Customer> 
        <TotalPurchase>sum(USPrice)</TotalPurchase> 
    </Customer> 
</Customers>
```

**XSLT Code:**

```
<Customers> 
   <xsl:for-each select="Customers/Customer"> 
     <Customer> 
        <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item"> 
           <TotalPurchase> 
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(/USPrice)"/> 
           </TotalPurchase> 
        </xsl:for-each> 
     </Customer> 
   </xsl:for-each> 
</Customers>
```

Can someone guide me how to achieve the output in XSLT 1.0. As the sum function didnt worked properly. It returs zero.

Comment: "*the sum function didnt worked*" Post your attempt. And please provide a well-formed XML as the input example: `Customer 1` is not a valid element name.

Comment: Do you want to sum the price as is, or the product of multiplying the price by quantity?

Comment: Thanks for your responses. 

This is my XSLT code. I just need the sum of the Items of each cutomer. Not by multiplying the quantity.

**XSLT Code:**

    <Customers>
    <xsl:for-each select="Customers/Customer">
    <Customer>
    <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item">
    <TotalPurchase>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(/USPrice)"/>
    </TotalPurchase>
    </Customer>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </Customers>

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the XSLT, as code is hard to read in comments? Also, can you format your XML so that it indented and on multiple lines, rather than just one long line. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sum the `USPrice` values for each `Customer`, without multiplying them by `Quantity` first (which seems strange to me), then do:

```
<xsl:template match="/Customers">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Customer">
            <Customer> 
                <TotalPurchase> 
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(Items/Item/USPrice)"/>
                </TotalPurchase>
            </Customer>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The result in your example will be:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <TotalPurchase>188.93</TotalPurchase>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <TotalPurchase>2064.9</TotalPurchase>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input XML doesn't look valid
for example  - you either need an attribute name if you want a value inside the customer tag or an id element inside the tag

```
e.g. <customer id=1> or <customer><id>1</id>
```

**Updated **
Your xpath selection is incorrect - once you have done the for-each on Items/Item you don't need the slash to refer to child elements
so your code should read

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(USPrice)"/>
```

However that won't solve your problem. In the for-each you are only pointing at one "item" node at a time so you will get the sum of only one USPrice at a time.

I believe

```
  <xsl:for-each select="Customers/Customer">
    <Customer>
            <TotalPurchase>
                <xsl:value-of select="sum(Items/Item/USPrice)"/>
            </TotalPurchase>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

should work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15312430)

Comment: @Regis - that's fair enough I have updated my answer now based on the XML provided by the asker. It does seem strange that i would need more reputation to make a clarifying comment than I do to answer a question

Comment: I don't write SO rules, but I guess the point is to avoid comment flood (which are not reviewed).

Answer (score 0):

Let's be clear what you have done wrong so you don't make the same mistake again.

```
        <xsl:for-each select="Items/Item"> 
           <TotalPurchase> 
              <xsl:value-of select="sum(/USPrice)"/> 
           </TotalPurchase> 
        </xsl:for-each>
```

The first thing you have done wrong is that "/" before `USPrice`. "/" takes you up to the root of the document, which you don't want - you want to select downwards from where you currently are, at an `Item` element. So drop the "/".

But that doesn't solve the problem. The sum() function adds a set of numbers, but `USPrice` starting at an `Item` only selects one number. Your mistake here is to think "I'm processing a list of things therefore I need to loop over them". Forget everything in that low-level procedural mind-set, you are dealing with a high-level declarative language here. What you want is:

```
       <TotalPurchase> 
          <xsl:value-of select="sum(Items/Item/USPrice)"/> 
       </TotalPurchase>
```